# Installing plugin "Fatal error: Cannot declare class Stripe\Stripe, because the name is already in use"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a theme that uses Stripe, and when installing the plugin Dokan Pro it gives me fatal error, i looked after the name class in the workspace of the plugin Stripe/Stripe and change the name class for MyStripe, but when i do that it gives me error another fatal error, and i looked for those directions and i dont know what to do in there, this a fragment of the code Helps.php, I intuitively thought of changing Stripe / Stripe to Stripe / MyStripe but it doesn't fix it.

```
    <?php

namespace WeDevs\DokanPro\Modules\Stripe;

use Stripe\Stripe;
use WeDevs\DokanPro\Modules\Stripe\Settings\RetrieveSettings;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * Stripe Helper class
 *
 * @since 3.0.3
 */
class Helper {

    public static function get_settings() {
        return RetrieveSettings::instance()->settings;
    }

    /**
     * Check wheter the 3d secure is enabled or not
     *
     * @since 3.0.3
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function is_3d_secure_enabled() {
        $settings = self::get_settings();

        if ( empty( $settings['enable_3d_secure'] ) || 'yes' !== $settings['enable_3d_secure'] ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check wheter we are paying with 3ds or non_3ds payment method
     *
     * @since 3.0.3
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function payment_method() {
        return self::is_3d_secure_enabled() ? '3ds' : 'non_3ds';
    }

    /**
     * Check wheter the gateway in test mode or not
     *
     * @since 3.0.3
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function is_test_mode() {
        $settings = self::get_settings();

        if ( empty( $settings['testmode'] ) || 'yes' !== $settings['testmode'] ) {
            return false;
        }

        return 'yes' === $settings['testmode'];
    }

    /**
     * Check wheter subscription module is enabled or not
     *
     * @since 3.0.3
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function has_subscription_module() {
        return dokan_pro()->module->is_active( 'product_subscription' );
    }

    /**
     * Set stripe app info
     *
     * @since 3.0.3
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function set_app_info() {
        Stripe::setAppInfo(
            'Dokan Stripe-Connect',
            DOKAN_PRO_PLUGIN_VERSION,
            'https://wedevs.com/dokan/modules/stripe-connect/',
            'pp_partner_Ee9F0QbhSGowvH'
        );
    }
```

[image: Fatal error imagen]

[image]

Comment: If you send me the entire theme and plugins folder (or even an entire clone with database entries), I can fix it for you and after that explain what the problem was and how you can fix similar problems in the future. If you're up to that, please send me an email to thaikolja [@] icloud.com.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to disable the stripe module inside the theme. Probably on functions.php has an include to stripe or do a big search for it.
It's better to modify themes (the child theme way) that to modify plugins.

Comment: Please, for the love of God, never ever touch plugin files. It's a cardinal error that sooner or later causes immense trouble.

Comment: I dont work with the child theme because i modify the theme php files, and i follow your suggestion and do the same i did with the plugin but in the theme, "class Stripe" to "class MyStripe" and it worked, hope still working the stripe from theme option